# Using Git under Proxy on Ubuntu

Tags: proxy, git, github

I do git clone using terminal on Ubuntu 14.04 i.e `git clone git@github.com:myusername/myrepo.git`. Before I did it, I set git to use proxy with command: `git config --global http.proxy proxyserver:port`. However, I got this erros message when trying to clone my repo on git. Help needed.

```
Cloning into 'MY REPO'... ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use an SSH connection with an HTTP proxy, it won't work. Github offers Git over HTTPS as well. So try:

```
git clone https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git
```

Comment: any solution for an `ssh` connection?